# Should we destroy the [elder-wand]?

Tags: discussion, tags

Consider the following two tags:

- [**[deathly-hallows]**](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deathly-hallows) 17 questions. Tag description:

  > Three magical objects in the Harry Potter universe that together give the owner ‘mastery over death‘. Specifically, they are the Elder Wand, Resurrection Stone and Cloak of Invisibility.
- [**[elder-wand]**](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elder-wand) 23 questions. Tag description:

  > The Elder Wand is the most powerful wand in the Harry Potter Universe.

But looking through the questions, it seems as if [deathly-hallows] is only for questions about the Stone and the Cloak, and anybody asking about the Elder Wand only uses [elder-wand].

It’s confusing to look for information about the Wand in the [deathly-hallows] tag, especially as it’s in the tag description, and find that there’s almost nothing there.

**I think we should retag all the questions that use [elder-wand] with [deathly-hallows].** We could alternatively make [elder-wand] a tag synonym for [deathly-hallows], but that seems unnecessary when it’s so seldom used.

(Or as a weak alternative, at least add the [deathly-hallows] tag to the [elder-wand] questions.)

Does this seem sensible?

Comment: I'm happy for you to just delete it if it's barely used.

Comment: @alexwlchan We should just remove the tag from all the questions that have it, in this case.  Tag synonyms are for when we have multiple tags that really refer to the same thing.  The term 'elder wand' is pretty generic, and might see some use outside of *Harry Potter*.

Comment: @alexwlchan Good plan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I suggested creating a synonym, @Keen proposed different in the comments:

> We should just remove the tag from all the questions that have it, in this case. Tag synonyms are for when we have multiple tags that really refer to the same thing. The term “elder wand” is pretty generic, and might see some use outside of Harry Potter. –  Keen♦ Apr 14 at 15:23

This has now been done: every question tagged with [elder-wand] has been retagged with [deathly-hallows], and sometimes [wandlore] where appropriate.

The tag will be deleted by the auto-cleanup script in the next day or so.

Answer (score 10):

Would a new user who isn't familiar with this meta tag be satisfied to see their "Elder-Wand" tagged post be tagged with "Deathly-Hallows" instead?

Knowing that the Elder Wand is one of them, and it being described as one in the Wiki, I think it'd be an appropriate synonym.

Answer (score -2):

Wouldn't the [elder-wand](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elder-wand) tag be useful for readers who have not yet read Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows?

Comment: Perhaps, but the Elder Wand isn’t mentioned until you get to *Deathly Hallows*. In fact, JK Rowling was quite cagey about telling us what Dumbledore’s wand was made of until the final book was published. I don’t think there are many readers who will be familiar with the Elder Wand, but haven’t read the final book. (Remember the tag is for the objects, not the book.)